# Drop Table Exception Intermittently doesn't work

Tags: sql, oracle, exception

I have been wrapping my "drop tables" in the following block to avoid raising 942 errors if the table doesn't exist:

```
BEGIN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE MY_TABLE1';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE MY_TABLE2';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE MY_TABLE3';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE MY_TABLE4';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE MY_TABLE5';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE MY_TABLE6';
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN 
IF SQLCODE != -942 THEN RAISE;
END IF;
END;
```

This works great most of the of time. However, intermittently it will seem to refuse to drop this table or that. It's not always the same table, and it doesn't always happen in any particular set of queries. It just happens...sometimes...for reasons I can't explain, hence my asking this question.

Has anyone else experienced this, and if so, what did you do about it?

Comment: What platform?  What version?

Comment: Any errors shown? Or just not dropped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely cause I can think of is the table is locked (outstanding commits) in another session. What error is reported?

Also there is a problem with your script - if TABLE1 has already been dropped, TABLE2...6 won't get dropped because your first DROP will jump to the exception.

Better to do this:

```
DECLARE
   PROCEDURE drp ( tName IN VARCHAR2 ) IS
   BEGIN
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'drop table ' || tName;
   EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN 
         IF SQLCODE != -942 THEN RAISE;
      END IF;
   END;
BEGIN
   drp ( 'TABLE1' );
   drp ( 'TABLE2' );
   drp ( 'TABLE3' );
   -- etc
END;
```

Comment: Specifically, it was the second thing you mentioned which caused the problem: that the first table which has already been dropped will cause the block to skip to the Exception statement. Adding in the procedur works like a charm! Thank you! I'm quite new to Oracle, with most of my SQL experience in SQL Server. This has helped so much.